# Custom range with FactoryGirl sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

In the old version something like this was possible ([more examples](http://www.pmamediagroup.com/2009/05/smarter-sequencing-in-factory-girl/)):

```
Factory.sequence(:email, 50..60) do |n|
  "user_#{n}@example.com"
end
```

Using this in the new FactoryGirl version will create an `NoMethodError: undefined method 'next' for 0..10:Range`.

In particular I have a model `user` which has multiple `time_entries`. I want to create default values. For simplicity each user should create `n` time entries. The entries are created like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :time_entry do
    start_time { generate(:time_entry_begin) }
    end_time { generate(:time_entry_end) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:time_entry_begin, 0..10) do |n|
    DateTime.now - n.hours
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do 
  sequence(:time_entry_end, 0..10) do |n|
    DateTime.now - n.hours + (1 + n).minutes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to pass an object that responds to `next`, e.g. an enumerator:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email, (50..60).cycle) { |n| "user_#{n}@example.com" }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.build(:user) #=> <#User @email="user_50@example.com">
FactoryGirl.build(:user) #=> <#User @email="user_51@example.com">
FactoryGirl.build(:user) #=> <#User @email="user_52@example.com">
# ...
FactoryGirl.build(:user) #=> <#User @email="user_59@example.com">
FactoryGirl.build(:user) #=> <#User @email="user_60@example.com">
# `cycle` will start over:
FactoryGirl.build(:user) #=> <#User @email="user_50@example.com">
```